# Django: set permission initial to logged user for dropdown in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I need to set permission to field 'user' to currently logged user in viewform of 'Userproject' created by that user.
Now in Viewform any user can choose from dropdown the username userproject belongs to. I want to set this field to hidden and default to logged user, and allow choose only for admin.

views.py:

```
    class UserprojectListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)



class UserprojectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Userproject
    template_name = 'userproject_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('userproject_list')
    fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'date_updated', 'date_until']

class UserprojectUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Userproject
    template_name = 'userproject_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('userproject_list')
    fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'date_updated', 'date_until']
```

forms.py:

```
class UserprojectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Userproject
    fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'date_updated', 'date_until'] #'date_created',  cannot add django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (date_created) specified for Userproject

def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    return name
```

userproject_form.html:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

Comment: This is explicitly covered in [the docs for the editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user). Also, your `clean_name` method is pointless and can be deleted.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  yes! this works! thanx